# How Do I rearrange or sort the Playlists I saved on Youtube?

Tags: youtube, youtube-playlist

I have saved some playlists on youtube. Now as time goes by, the list keeps on growing, and it seems to have sorted itself based on Newest First.[image: Youtube Saved Playlists]

I could not find any way to change the sorting order.
Actually what I want is on my homepage, I see the oldest saved playlist on top and latest on the bottom.

Answer (score 3):

I could not find a way to change the order of playlists in the sidebar but came up with the following solution:

1. Click on 'Your Videos' in the sidebar
2. Click on 'MANAGE VIDEOS' at Top right of screen (creates a new tab)
3. Click on 'Playlists' in sidebar (creates a new tab)
4. Click on the drop down Next to 'View:' (top right, under the search input)
5. Select one of the options: Newest Created,
   Oldest Created,
   A-Z,
   Z-A
6. Save the tab as a bookmark

Note: The bookmark will retain the selected sort order and will also reflect any changes.